# x64dbg jump arrows disappears when scrolling the page

Tags: debugging, ollydbg, x64dbg

I am working with x64dbg.
in this app we have some arrows in the leftside of the main page that shows the jumps source and destination.
now I am seeing one jump that is long and when I want to go from source to the destination, I must scroll the page.
when I scroll the page the arrow disappears.
I want to see the arrow all of time that I am scrolling to the destination.
this has been solved in ollydbg.
is there any option to fix this?

I just searched and checked app options